# Persist additional dataSource.read parameters on paganation in Kendo data grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datasource

I have a Kendo Grid that loads data via ajax with a call to server-side ASP.NET read method:

```
 public virtual JsonResult Read(DataSourceRequest request, string anotherParam)
```

In my client-side JS, I trigger a read when a button is clicked:

```
grid.dataSource.read( { anotherParam: 'foo' });
grid.refresh();
```

This works as expected, only I lose the additional param when I move through the pages of results in the grid, or use the refresh icon on the grid to reload the data.

How do I persist the additional parameter data in the grid?

I have tried setting

```
grid.dataSource.data
```

directly, but without much luck. I either get an error if I pass an object, or no effect if I pass the name of a JS function that returns data.

Comment: What does the code for your datasource look like? You might be able to use the datasource.transport.parameterMap to pass the parameter everytime it is read.

Comment: Jeremy, did you ever resolve this? I have the same problem. I cannot retain the information of an additional parameter after I navigate the grid

Answer (score 4):

if you want to pass additional parameters to Read ajax datasource method (server side), you may use

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            ...
            .Read(read => read.Action("Read", controllerName, new { anotherParam= "foo"}))
            ...
        )
```

if you want to pass additional parameters through client scripting you may use datasource.transport.parameterMap, something as below

```
parameterMap: function(data, type) {
  if (type == "read") {

     return { request:kendo.stringify(data), anotherParam:"foo" }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the datasource.transport.parameterMap

```
parameterMap: function(data, type) {
  if (type == "read") {

     return kendo.stringify(data, anotherParam);
  }
```

I'm not sure where your other param is coming from, but this is generally how I send extra parameters to the server.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.parameterMap

Answer (score 0):

if use datasource object :

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: '/Api/GetData',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // optional
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: function () {
                            return {
                                additionalParam: value
                            };
                        }
                    },
                //parameterMap: function (data, type) {
                // and so use this property to send additional param
                //    return $.extend({ "additionalParam": value }, data);
                //}
                    },
            schema: {
                type: "json",
                data: function (data) {
                    return data.result;
            },
            },
            pageSize: 5,
            serverPaging: true,
            serverSorting: true
        });
```

and set options in grid:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    autoBind: false,
    dataSource: dataSource,
    selectable: "multiple cell",
    allowCopy: true,
    columns: [
        { field: "productName" },
        { field: "category" }
    ]
});
```

and in click event this code :

```
dataSource.read();
```

and in api web method this action:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetData([FromUri]KendoGridParams/* define class to get parameter from javascript*/ _param)
        {
           // use _param to filtering, paging and other actions
            try
            {

                var result = Service.AllCustomers();
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { result = result });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new { result = string.Empty });
            }
        }
```

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

**To persist the updated value of the additional parameter through pagination, you will need to create a global variable and save the value to it.**

```
var anotherParamValue= "";//declare a global variable at the top. Can be assigned some default value as well instead of blank
```

Then, when you trigger the `datasource` `read` event, **you should save the value to the global variable** we created earlier.

```
anotherParamValue = 'foo';//save the new value to the global variable
grid.dataSource.read( { anotherParam: anotherParamValue });
grid.refresh();
```

**Now, this is important.** In your `datasource` object `transport.read.data` must be set to use a function as shown below:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: '/Api/GetData',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // optional
                        dataType: "json",
                        //Must be set to use a function, to pass dynamic values of the parameter
                        data: function () {
                            return {
                                additionalParam: anotherParamValue //get the value from the global variable
                            };
                        }
                    },

                    },
            schema: {
                type: "json",
                data: function (data) {
                    return data.result;
            },
            },
            pageSize: 5,
            serverPaging: true,
            serverSorting: true
        });
```

Now on every page button click, you should get the updated value of the `anotherParam` which is currently set to `foo`